# Can I modify http response status in completion block?

Tags: spray

Is there way to modify the http status code inside of the complete {} block? I've defined a Marshaller to work with `scalaz.concurrent.Task` like so:

`implicit def taskMarshaller[A](implicit m: Marshaller[A]) =
    Marshaller[scalaz.concurrent.Task[A]]{(task, ctx) =>
      task.runAsync(_.fold(l => throw l, r => m(r, ctx)))
    }`

and I do

`complete { 
      Task {...} 
  }`

I'd like to be able to modify the http status code in the repsonse based on the results of the Task.

Comment: Why can't you put that behavior into the task marshaller itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is is to use a `ToResponseMarshaller` for `scalaz.concurrent.Task[(StatusCode, A)]` as follows:

`implicit def scalazTaskWithStatusMarshaller[A](implicit m: ToResponseMarshaller[(StatusCode, A)]): ToResponseMarshaller[scalaz.concurrent.Task[(StatusCode, A)]] =
    ToResponseMarshaller[scalaz.concurrent.Task[(StatusCode, A)]] { (task, ctx) =>
      task.runAsync(_.fold(l => throw l, r => m(r, ctx)))
    }`